# How do I get the MAX ID of a row via C# (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am fairly new to C#, and I need to get the MAX ID of a Member (MemberID). I have searched Stack Overflow and have found numerous resources, but have been unable to successfully implement a solution.

The way it works:

There is an EMR ID which is unique to each person, but the MemberID can be different because they switch from plan to plan. I need to find the latest record created (which is why I need the MAX) because that means it's the current profile

Thank you.

```
public List<MemberDTO> getMembers(int planID)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new CompanyHHCEntities())
        {
            var membersList = (from member in dbContext.PQIP_Member
                               where member.PlanID == planID
                               && (member.TeamAssigned ?? false)
                               select new MemberDTO()
                               {
                                   MemberID = member.ID,
                                   EMR_ID = member.EMR_ID ?? 0,
                                   FullName = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName,
                                   Phone1 = member.HomePhone,
                                   Phone2 = member.Phone2,
                                   Street1 = member.Street1,
                                   Street2 = member.Street2,
                                   City = member.City,
                                   State = member.State,
                                   Zip = member.Zip
                               }).OrderBy(a => a.FullName).ToList();

            return membersList;
        }
    }
```

I've tried :

```
MemberID = members.Select(a => a.MemberID).Max(),
```

Comment: Do you want to get the max id of the resulting query (the returning `List<MemberDTO>` after calling `getMembers`)

Comment: Is the ID a string or a number.  Max will only work on numbers.

Comment: @IvanGarcíaTopete Yes. I am only trying to return one record per Member when they have multiple ones.

Comment: @jdweng ID is an int.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: @Euphoric 1) MemberID = member.Select(member => member.ID).Max()

Comment: @Euphoric 2) Tried putting membersList into another variable and getting the MAX ID of that.

Comment: Usse : from member in dbContext.PQIP_Member.OrderByDescending(x => x.MemberID)  Then then max will be the first item in the list.  You query is using an OrderBy Fullname so how can you order by name and id at same time?

Comment: Update your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: @Euphoric Will do. Apologies.

Comment: I still don't understand from which collection of members you want to get the maximum ID? If you can answer that question then solution is trivial. You already know Max().

Comment: to add to the above question - what ID will you use to find the max, if it is memberID, would the same member not have the same memberID across all records.

Comment: @Rakesh The way it works is that there an EMR ID that is unique to each person, but the MemberID can be different because they switch from plan to plan. I need to find the latest record created (which is why I need the MAX) because that means it's the current profile.

Comment: I think I understand. But in that case your whole query is wrong and not just problem of Max Id. But about finding single member record with highest MemberId when grouped by EMR_ID. Is that correct?

Comment: You could just use SQL and be done with it in 3.5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I cannot guarantee this will work in SQL nor that it is correct per your specification.

```
public List<MemberDTO> getMembers(int planID)
{
    using (var dbContext = new CompanyHHCEntities())
    {
        var membersList = 
            dbContext.PQIP_Member
                .Where(member => member.PlanID == planID && (member.TeamAssigned ?? false))
                .GroupBy(member=>member.EMR_ID) // create groups of members where member has same EMR_ID
                .SelectMany(grp=>grp.OrderByDesc(member=>member.ID).Take(1)) // from each group, select member with highest ID
                .Select(member => new MemberDTO()
                           {
                               MemberID = member.ID,
                               EMR_ID = member.EMR_ID ?? 0,
                               FullName = member.FirstName + " " + member.LastName,
                               Phone1 = member.HomePhone,
                               Phone2 = member.Phone2,
                               Street1 = member.Street1,
                               Street2 = member.Street2,
                               City = member.City,
                               State = member.State,
                               Zip = member.Zip
                           })
                .OrderBy(a => a.FullName)
                .ToList();

        return membersList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Euphoric. This works exactly the way I need it to. I really appreciate your time today.